# Is there a way to have evenly sized ticks for recharts axis while keeping my max value?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have a data array like below which I want to show in a particular way using recharts.

```
const severityExampleData: any = [
    {symptom_type: 'chest pain', mild: 1, moderate: 2, severe: 1, total: 4},
    {symptom_type: 'pursiness', mild: 2, moderate: 1, severe: 10, total: 13},
    {symptom_type: 'cough', mild: 0, moderate: 0, severe: 1, total: 1},
];
```

I want my Y-axis to have even tick sizes and I want them to be 5 ticks, So I used the following solution.

```
    <ResponsiveContainer width='100%' aspect={4.8/3.0}>
        <BarChart data={data} margin={{top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}}>
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3" vertical={false} />
            <XAxis reversed dataKey="symptom_type" tickLine={false} axisLine={false}/>
            <YAxis orientation='right' tickLine={false} axisLine={false} tickCount={5} domain={['auto', MAX]}/>
            <Tooltip />
            {fieldNames.map((value: any, i:number) => {
                console.log(value);
                return (
                    <Bar name={value} barSize={50} 
                    radius={i === fieldNames.length - 1 ? [10, 10, 0, 0]: [0, 0, 0, 0]} 
                    dataKey={value} stackId='a' fill={colors[i]}/>);
            })}
        </BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
```

And the result will be as follows.[even ticks image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS6tV.png)

But I want my high bound tick to be the sum of my 'total' fields (which in this case is 18).
To achive this I tried to set 'domain' property in 'YAxis' component to ['0', MAX].(MAX is the sum of my 'total's) But now my chart looks like this.[max value for ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khysq.png)

Actually I want 5 ticks to evenly divide my Y-axis and my highest tick to be the MAX.
Sorry if my english was rough, I am not very good in that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it using

```
const tickArray = [0, Math.trunc(MAX/4), Math.trunc(MAX/2), Math.trunc(3*MAX/4), MAX];
```

and

```
ticks={tickArray} domain={[0, MAX]}
```

in my `<YAxis>` component and removed

```
tickCount={5}
```

Comment: do you know why it is necessary to set BOTH ticks AND domain? Domain should be given from ticks, right?

Comment: They are different.  Ticks are the labels that show up, domain is the scope of the full axis.  So the domain could go from 0 - 100 while the ticks only include [30, 50, 70] if for some reason you only wanted 3 tickes in the middle of your yaxis.